# Bootstrap-Select Chinese Character Search in Country Dropdown(in Chinese Language)

Tags: jquery, chinese-locale

I'm having an issue with the BootStrap-Select.
When it comes to perform Character search with in dropdown options, It works fine with the English Alphabets but does not work at all for Russian, Greeks or Chinese Specific Dropdown options with their respective keywords or Keyboard keys.

I found a place where it checks the keyboard key code and search based on the letter that appears against that keybaord key code.
So I have created 3 new versions of same JS File and added Greeks, Russian and Chinese keyboard key code specific Characters.

Now, It is working fine for Greeks and Russian but not working at all for Chinese.

I seems like Chinese 1 letter may be a combination of multiple characters. Not Sure.

So I need help with this if Any one have ever done such kind of thing in Bootstrap-Select and made the character/letter search work for Chinese.

Note: I'm not talking about Search Input field. We don't want that. We just simply want Letter or character search work for other languages as it is working for English letters.

I have tried using characters from this Site to map with the Keyboard key codes:
https://www.branah.com/chinese

But the dropdown of country names does not contains such Chinese characters at the start of the any name except "中".

Here is a screenshot:
[Chinese Country Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3dn3.png)